# jQuery processor usage when referring to same event multiple times

Tags: jquery, performance

Are there any advantages of using the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollPos = parseInt( $(document).scrollTop() );
  $(".div1").css({"background-position-y":scrollPos});
  $(".div2").css({"background-position-y":scrollPos});
});
```

instead of splitting it up into two function, like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollPos = parseInt( $(document).scrollTop() );
  $(".div1").css({"background-position-y":scrollPos});
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollPos = parseInt( $(document).scrollTop() );
  $(".div2").css({"background-position-y":scrollPos});
});
```

Naturally the second option will increase the processor usage marginally since it has to calculate new values for the same variable more than once. But, assuming a relatively modern machine, are there any advantages of choosing the first over the second example?

Comment: Well, what's the advantage of the verbose version ?

Comment: Yes, the advantage being you're only typing `var scrollPos = parseInt( $(document).scrollTop() );` once.

Comment: Note that you could also factorize the first one as `$(".div1,.div2").css`

Comment: The first version also applies 1 event handlers vs the second assigning 2. So there's another small performance, but unless you do this thousands of times in a file then you won't see the difference in using either option.

Comment: So, appart from that there are really no other disadvantages?

Comment: There's a performance disadvantage to #2 (very minor on a modern desktop, but possibly noticable on older machines in IE<9) and a maintenance disadvantage to both vs using `$(".div1,.div2")` but moreso for #2 since if you added a 3rd div you'd be adding yet another event if you followed the same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not payed by the Line Of Code, then any version longer than this one is only adding maintenance costs :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $(".div1,.div2").css({"background-position-y": $(document).scrollTop()});
});
```

and is slower but that's not really relevant with today's browsers speed.

Just in case you didn't notify this change, I also removed the `parseInt` as `scrollTop` returns an integer.